# I am getting a segmentation fault core dumped when using strtok

Tags: c, csv, parsing, segmentation-fault

I am trying to read numbers from a csv file, then pass those into a char*[] that I called pTokens. Everything seems to work fine, as in the char *[] gets populated, but when I try to access an element from the array, I get a segmentation fault.  (It also seems to crash when I try and manually input the file name, hence why it is commented out. But that's a problem for another time.)

```
FILE *infile = NULL;
char line[1024] = "", copyLine[1024] = "";
char *pTokens[1024] = { NULL };
int index = 0;
int i;
int j = 0;
.
.
.

case 8:

printf("Enter the file name (test.csv):\n");
//scanf("%s", name);
infile = fopen("values.csv", "r");
if(infile != NULL){
  printf("successfully opened\n");
  fgets(line, 100, infile);
  strcpy(copyLine, line);
  pTokens[index] = strtok(copyLine, ",");
  puts(line);
  while (pTokens[index] != NULL)
  {
    ++index;
    pTokens[index] = strtok(NULL, ","); // token
  }
  while(pTokens[j] != NULL){
     puts(pTokens[j]); 
     j++;
  }

}else{
  printf("Failed to open file.\n");
  cond = 0;
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
1. Create a new node
2. Delete a node
3. Print the Pre-Order of the tree
4. Print the In-Order of the tree.
5. Find min of the tree
6, Find max of the tree.
8. Create Tree from CSV.
9. Exit.


8
Enter the file name (test.csv):
successfully opened
50,30,20,40,70,60,80

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My instinct, is that I am not accessing the strings in the array correctly, causing the crash, but I'm unsure. Thank you.

Comment: `puts(pTokens[1]);` what if `pTokens[1] == NULL` ? you didn't test that. have you tried to print the value of the pointer before de-referencing it?

Comment: aside;: don't forget to close the file once it's read.

Comment: Aside: the delimiter set `","` should be `",\n"` to catch the newline retained by `fgets` (in both calls to `strtok`).

Comment: maybe creating a [mcve] would help us help you.

Comment: I tested pTokens[j] being null, with the same outcome. I have updated my question.

Comment: What happens to your initialised variables before you reach `case 8:`? If you are reading several lines from the file, make sure you reset `index = 0;` before using it.

Comment: Case 8 is the only case where I am reading from the file, so index is not altered anywhere else

Comment: [mcve] is the key here. Or someone would already have pointed the problem out. create a standalone example where you're not reading from a file, but passing the input as hardcoded string. if you can crash a standalone program, other people would be able to fix it for you

Comment: Yes – you have now changed the code. It is also suspicious that "it seems to crash when I try and manually input the file name".

Comment: as Weather suggests, you may have another corruption which crashes a perfectly okay code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me being a noob to C is showing. 
I forgot to put

```
#include <string.h>
```

in  my file. This solved my not being able to read from pTokens.

Comment: Please enable and deal with all compiler warnings. Treat them as errors.

Comment: Weather Vane - Yeah, I need to do that.
Side note - How can I mark my question as being closed? Can I just put [Closed] in the title?